Move a file with python with a partially matching name
Admitted newby here so forgive me if this is incredibly simple, I just can't find a solution that works.
There is a file generated in my environment every day which I want to move from one place to another.   Every day the filename is appended with the day's date, so each day the filename is different. I want to automate the process of moving the file, via a cron schedule, but as I mentioned, the filename changes every day. Is there any way I can have a partial match or wildcard match with the (src)?
Current Code is:
import shutil

shutil.move("/Users/Me/LocationA/filename_20240621.txt", "/Users/Me/LocationB/nameofmyfile.txt")

This works if the src matches exactly, but I would like to figure out how to match anything that matches /Users/Me/LocationA/filename_*.  Any help is appreciated!

You can use a regex pattern: \/Users\/Me\/LocationA\/filename_[^\r\n]*\.(?:txt|csv)?

You should be able to find files with partial name matches utilizing regex and os package of Python.
import os
import re
import shutil


def move_partially_matching_files(src, dst, pattern):
    regex = re.compile(pattern)
    
    # In case the directory does not exist
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for file in files:
            if regex.match(file):
                src_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                dst_path = os.path.join(dst, file)
                shutil.move(src_path, dst_path)


src = '/path/to/your/source_folder'
dst = '/path/to/your/destination_folder'
# d{8} to match exactly 8 digits after the underscore
pattern = r'^filename_\d{8}\.txt$'

move_partially_matching_files(src, dst, pattern)

